# How to list paintings based on number of votes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

Ive got a painting model. votes is embedded into painting. How can i query all paintings and order by the number of votes? IN theory, I would like to list down all paintings starting with the ones with the most votes.

For reference purposes. Here is the definition of the two models:

```
class Painting
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :title, :type => String

  embeds_many :votes
  ...
end

class Vote
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  embedded_in :painting, :inverse_of => :votes
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using **counter cache column**. Once you implement this functionality like mentioned here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column, paintings table will contain votes_count column which holds the number of votes for each painting

Then you can easily add named_scope in your painting.rb model to order paintings by number of votes:

```
class Painting
  named_scope :order_by_maximum_votes, :order => "votes_count DESC"
end
```

Then you can fetch all paintings like this way:

`@paintings = Painting.all.order_by_maximum_votes`

Comment: How is this accepted if mongoid has no counter cache mechanism??

Answer (score 0):

If you still don't want to use add one more column in database, you can have another simple option. Fetch all paintings from database and then sort them by votes count:

```
# It fetches all paintings needed
@paintings = Painting.all
# Then sort them by number of votes
@paintings = @paintings.sort {|p| p.votes.length}
```

Comment: I get NoMethodError: undefined method `sort' for main:Object. Another solution I found (and as you were suggesting) was to add an extra column to keep track of the total count of votes

Comment: Yes I guess sort can operate on array only. So we should make sure that @paintings holds an array. Then it should not throw an error. By the way, using counter cache column is also a good way :-)